# HTTP rest api xml flutter authentication

Tags: rest, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a client app in flutter for a music server, the server uses this api http://www.subsonic.org/pages/api.jsp version 1.12.0
This is what I have so far:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


main() async {
  String username = 'demo';
  String password = 'demo1';
  String version = '1.12.0';
  String client = 'democlient';
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password$version$client'));
  print(basicAuth);

  Response r = await get('http://demo.org/rest/');
      headers: {'authorization': basicAuth});
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(r.body);

  Map <String, String> headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/xml',
    'accept': 'application/xml',
    'authorization': basicAuth,
 };
}
```

this is broken though.